# Get GeoJSON from GeoServer with filter

Tags: json, jsonp, gis, geojson, geoserver

I have published a map service in GeoServer, and there are thousands of features in there.
When I generate GeoJSON from Layer Preview with out "maxFeatures=50", the process is getting extremely slow. So I was wondering that if there is a way that I can put some filter in the request url so I can get specifically what I want instead of all features?

For example, I want get features whose name equals to "test", can I make the url:

http://domain.com:8188/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Gistic:V_STRUCTURES_WFS&outputFormat=json&name=test

in order to filter?

If not, is there any other way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110399/geoserver-wfs-can-i-pass-in-filter-parameters-via-the-url

similar post with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the [geoserver documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html) (section GetFeature) its is stated that you can filter on properties exactly like you suggested with &name=test.
If you want to filter on "test" and "rest" you can comma separate the values like this:

```
&name=test,rest
```

You can also filter on bbox. If you want more filter options you'll have to do a POST instead of a GET.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace each character ":" by %3A

good luck